# In C++, removing an object from a list

Tags: c++, stl, remove-if

I'm writing a program which is more or less like this :

```
#include <list>

list<MyClass> things;

class MyClass {
   // some stuff

   void remove() {
       things.remove_if(THING_IS_ME);
   }
};
```

What do I need to write instead of THING_IS_ME?

In other words, I'm using a global STL list as a collection of things. At some point, an object which is in the list recognises that it is redundant and wants to a) get itself removed from the list, and b) get itself destructed.

How do I do this?

I haven't written C++ for about 15 years and am a bit confused by this page here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

What are these Predicates? Does C++ have higher-order functions now?

Comment: Ah. No, I didn't realize that at all!!! I just assumed it would store references to whatever I put in it. It's been 15 years ... guess I'm still thinking in Java. :-(  Thanks

Comment: You do realize that the STL containers store *copies* of things you insert, right? That means instances of `MyClass` better be comparable (e.g. via `operator==`) - you can't just compare the addresses as they will always be different. If having copies of `MyClass` makes no sense, then you're probably better off with [a pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: @interstar: (Sorry, I deleted my comment right before you replied.) Yeah, the C++ language uses copy-semantics by default. The language requires that you make things like references explicit in the code. If having copies of `MyClass` doesn't make sense, you can use [a pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). I highly recommend that you pick up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or you will be tripped up by issues like this in the future.

Comment: I guess the point is, that really I should explicitly be creating my list<*MyThing> and then just storing pointers in it. Then I can use remove(this) to compare the pointer values?

Comment: @interstar: Yes, that can work. Remember that if you do it like that you have to take care of any memory management issues. For example, you have to consider object lifetimes and the fact that `std::list` won't automatically `delete` pointers that you remove from the container. That's why I recommended [a pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) which takes care of that for you.

Comment: yes. In silico. Thanks, I'll look into Boost.

Comment: @interstar I don't think it's a good idea to bring Java programming into C++. If you can avoid memory management then you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Originally a set of comments, but rewritten as an answer after discovering what the OP actually wanted to do.)*

You do realize that the STL containers store *copies* of things you insert, right? That means instances of `MyClass` better be comparable (e.g. via `operator==`) - you can't just compare the addresses as they will always be different.

If having copies of MyClass makes no sense, then you're probably better off with [a pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

That being said, the C++ language uses copy-semantics by default. The language requires that you make things like references explicit in the code. I highly recommend that you pick up [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or you will be tripped up by issues like this in the future.

Comment: OK. I'm marking this as the answer I wanted, because it really was the answer I needed. Even though it isn't quite what I asked for in the question. Ie. I need to use pointer explicitly in the list and an ordinary remove. (At least until I get into Boost.)

Answer (score 5):

Things have changed dramatically in C++ in the past 15 years. In July 1994 Alexander Stepanov's proposal of a library that incorporates his ideas of generic programming received the final approval from the ANSI/ISO committee. This library that we conveniently call today the STL subsequently became a standard C++ library. The story of the STL is about as fascinating as the ideas behind it, and it definitely is worth the read.

The `std::remove_if()` function that you found is just another reflection of this philosophy that became part of C++'s modern identity. In short, this is a generic function that will work on any container (sequence) of elements and with any(thing that acts like a) condition. To this effect, you must provide the function two things:

1. a couple of *iterators* that delimit the range of elements you wish to work on;
2. and a *predicate* that, when invoked on an element, returns true if the element is to be removed and false otherwise.

As it turns out, in this case the predicate you want is that of equality. And because it is such a common task to remove elements based on equality the standard also provides the `std::remove()` function, which assumes an implicit equality predicate. Of course, you must make sure that elements can compare:

```
bool operator==(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    // return true if the two are equal, and false otherwise.
}
```

We can then use our predicate to remove elements of type `MyClass`:

```
std::remove(things.begin(), things.end(), *this);  // if *this == elem
```

Recall that the standard function `std::remove()` works on *any* container, even ones that haven't been created yet. Because every kind of container has its own way of removing elements, this function can't really perform the removal without knowing implementation details of the container it works on. So instead, the `std::remove()` function swaps elements around such that the elements "removed" are at the end of the container. Then, it returns an iterator pointing at the first element of the consecutive elements "removed".

```
typedef std::list<MyClass>::iterator iter;
iter first_removed = std::remove(things.begin(), things.end(), *this);
```

Finally, we truly remove elements by calling the specific container's removal function, which works on a single position in the list or on a range of consecutive elements to remove:

```
things.erase(first_removed, things.end());
```

It is not uncommon to see this sort of code in a single line:

```
things.erase(std::remove(things.begin(), things.end(), *this),
             things.end());
```

This all may seem overwhelming and complicated, but it has a few advantages. For one thing, this design of the standard library supports dynamic programming. It also allows the standard library to offer containers with very slim interfaces, as well as few free functions that work on many different kinds of containers. It allows you to quickly create a container and instantly gain all the features of the standard library to work with it. Alternatively, it allows you to quickly write a generic function that instantly works with all standard containers -- those written already and those not written yet.

Answer (score 0):

First, a simple hand-written loop:

```
for( list<MyClass>::iterator it = things.begin(); it != things.end(); /*  */ ) {
    if( qualifiesForDelete( *it ) ) {
        it = things.erase( it );
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Second, using the the `remove_if` algorithm. `remove_if` being an algorithm, as opposed to a member function of `list`, can't actually delete any elements, rather it moves the elements-to-be-deleted towards the end of list. Subsequently `erase` has to be called. This is a very important idiom, [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), that must be learnt.

```
things.erase( 
    remove_if( things.begin(), things.end(), deletionPredicate ), 
    things.end() 
);
```

where `deletionPredicate` is a function or function-object that takes a single argument of type  and returns `bool`. The elements for which `true` is returned are considered to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The `remove_if` function takes three parameters: two iterators that define the range you're working on, and a predicate (test function that returns `bool`). The start iterator points to the first element you want to work on; the end iterator points to the element after the last element in the range.

In the example from the [page you linked to](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/), the predicate is the line of code that says

```
bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }
```

To make your code do what you want, you'd need to write something like this:

```
things.remove_if(things.begin(), things.end(), SomePredicateFunction);
```

and you'd define `SomePredicateFunction` like so (replacing `true` with an appropriate test):

```
bool SomePredicateFunction (MyClass c) { return true; }
```